# Node.js: Render JSON API data as HTML response to a server

Tags: node.js

Cant figure this one out, any help appreciated. Im reading JSON data and parsing it to HTML and outputting it to nodejs httpserver. This works fine.

But I'd like to read the data from API using Axios. doesnt seem to work. It crashes the entire httpserver.

Below code snippet:

```
var axios = require("axios");
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

//Fetch the API data
function getData() {
  const promise = axios
    .get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=star+wars&apikey=cbbc6750")
    .then(res => {
      const data = response.data;
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.warn("Error while getting data!");
    });
}
// Run through the data
function parse(data) {
  console.log("Parse");
  var html = "<table border='1'>";
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    html += "<tr>";
    html += "<td>" + data.Search[i].Title + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + data.Search[i].Type + "</td>";
    html += "</tr>";
  }
  html += "</table>";
  console.log(html);
  return html;
}

// create a server object:
http
  .createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });

 // This works perfectly when Im loading the data from a file   
 //  var data = require("./starwars.json");
// it doesnt with axios
    var data = getData();
    var html = parse(data);
    response.write(html);
    console.log(data);

    response.end(); //end the response
  })
  .listen(8081); //the server object listens on port 8080
// Loop though the data
```

Comment: `getData` is an async function but you try to call it in the response handler synchrounously: `var data = getData();`

Comment: Thanks @lependu . What would be the best practice for this kind of code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal, not optimized version. Give it a try. You need the `parse` function and require your dependencies of course.

```
const server = http.createServer(function (request, respose) {
  axios
    .get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=star+wars&apikey=cbbc6750")
    .then(res => {
       const body = parse(res.data)
       response.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/html' })
       response.end(body)
    })
    .catch(err => {
       // Handle error if axios fetching fails
       response.writeHead(500, { 'content-type': 'text/plain' })
       response.end('Internal Server Error')
     })
})

server.listen(port, err => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(`Server listens on  ${server.address().host}:${server.address().port}`)
})
```

As for optimazation i suggest read through the [node http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) and the [node stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) documentation. The basic node way would be something like:

1. insted of axios use [http.get](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_url_options_callback)
2. instead of sync parse function use a [transform stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform)
3. [pipe](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) them together with the [http ServerResponse](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) (the response from the http.createServer's callback)